# How do I use Jitsi Meet in an EmberJS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js

In my Ember app I'm using ember-inject-script which I installed:

```
npm install --save-dev ember-inject-script
```

The controller.js file for my page looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import injectScript from 'ember-inject-script';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    var url = "https://meet.jit.si/external_api.js";
    injectScript(url);
    var domain = "meet.jit.si";
    var room = "JitsiMeetAPIExample";
    var width = 700;
    var height = 700;
    var htmlElement = document.querySelector('#meet');
    var api = new JitsiMeetExternalAPI(domain, room, width, height, 
              htmlElement);
  }
});
```

The Template is this:

```
<h2>Jitsi Meet</h2>
<div id="meet"></div>
{{outlet}}
```

Yet I get a console error:

> **Error while processing route:** projects.index JitsiMeetExternalAPI is not defined ReferenceError: JitsiMeetExternalAPI is not defined

Comment: Note that I'm using the Jitsi Meet API: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/api.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `injectScript` in asynchronous so you can't use `JitsiMeetExternalAPI` very next statement. You need to use `then`.
- Another issue is, you are accessing the DOM element in controller init method, which will not be available. generally controller is not DOM aware. for this I will encourage you to write Component and use `didInsertElement` hook

One more alternative approach to load js at the required time, is in routes beforeModel hook, you can just use Ember.$.getJSON(url).

```
beforeModel(){
 return Ember.$.getJSON(url);
}
```